# Java environment.getProperty returns null

Tags: java, spring, maven, environment-variables

I am trying to retrieve variables I put inside an application.properties file with an Environment object. I have to select just one variable following the configured_language.
I have no problems retrieving the configured_language from the file with @Value, but when I try to retrieve another value with environment.getProperty, it returns null.
I have to make my project with the Spring framework, not Spring Boot. This is my first project with Spring.
Here is my code :

HelloWorldService.java :

```
@Service
public class HelloWorldService implements EnvironmentAware {
    
    @Value("${configured_language}")
    private String language;
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    public String hello() {
        String property = this.language + "_hello_world";
        String msg = this.environment.getProperty(property);
        return msg;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public Environment getEnvironment() {
        return environment;
    }

    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }   
}
```

App.java :

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    HelloWorldService helloWorld = context.getBean(HelloWorldService.class);
    System.out.println(helloWorld.hello());
    }
}
```

application.properties :

```
configured_language=NL
native_hello_world=Bonjour le monde avec Spring!
EN_hello_world=Hello World in Spring!
NL_hello_world=Hallo Wereld met Spring!
GER_hello_world=Hallo Welt mit Schpring!
```

applicationContext.xml :

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="vd.vdourson.week4.helloWorld.service"/>
```

The structure of my project :

[image]

I tried to add a constructor for HelloWorldService but it didn't work.
When I print the environment variable I have this :

```
StandardEnvironment {activeProfiles=[]
, defaultProfiles=[default]
, propertySources=[PropertiesPropertySource 
  {name='systemProperties'}
  , SystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}
]}
```

When I print `this.environment.getProperty("EN_hello_word")` inside the hello method, I have null.

Comment: why do you assume what you have in your properties file to automatically be in the environment properties?

Comment: From this site https://stackabuse.com/how-to-access-property-file-values-in-spring-boot/ and this one https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-read-application-properties/ , and others. But I am not working with Spring Boot, just "plain" Spring. Could it be the problem?

Comment: have you checked that this: this.language + "_hello_world" does in fact return EN_hello_world, sure there are no extra spaces or anything like that?

Comment: I found the solution. Added @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") to the class, and now it works just fine. I just have to understand why <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/> in my applicationContext.xml doesn't do the job...